# ZipArchive extractTo throwing exception

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-ziparchive

I'm using **ZipArchive** within a **Code Igniter** framework PHP Application.
It's working fine to extact however code igniter is throwing an error at the **extractTo** step but it doesn't  crash the application and the application continues till the end but this error is still triggered and displayed by code igniter. The directory exists before extractTo and it extracts properly and keeps going but why is this error thrown?

```
        $zipVar = new ZipArchive;
        $res = $zipVar->open($input_zip); 
        if ($res === TRUE) 
        {                           
             $zipVar->extractTo($target_dir);
             $zipVar->close();                        
         }
```

[image]

Comment: what is $zip and what is $zipVar?

Comment: yeah shouldn't it be `$zipVar = new ZipArchive;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$input_zip = "" ; // 
$target_dir = "" ; //


if(!is_file($input_zip) || !is_readable($target_dir))
{
    die("Can't Read Input");
}

if(!is_dir($target_dir) || !is_writable($target_dir))
{
    die("Can't Write to Target");
}

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($input_zip);
if ($res === TRUE)
{
    echo 'ok';
    $zip->extractTo($target_dir);
    $zip->close();
}
else {
    die("Failed");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Baba, I just tried this unfortunately it still goes through without issues but code igniter throws that error

Comment: The new error is stright foward ... You are trying to include a file that does not exist